# Is there a way to share a link via Nearby Share & receive the link via a custom app on the second device using Nearby Connections API?

Tags: android, google-nearby, google-nearby-connections

I want to share data using Nearby Share so I can avoid putting an app on device 1. Then I want to accept that data on a custom app on device 2 so I can transform it and do something else with it.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

If your app is initiating the share, use the intent extra `com.google.android.gms.nearby.sharing.EXTRA_REQUIRED_PACKAGE` to pass an Android package name. This will prioritize launching your app on the receiving phone and will redirect to the Play Store if your app is not installed.

If your app is receiving the share, use a custom file extension and register your app as the default handler for that file type.

```
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
  <data android:scheme="file" />
  <data android:host="*" />
  <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
  <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.insert_custom_file_extension_here" />
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: If our app is receiving the share and if we're not sharing a specific file, but rather some blob of text, could we still use this method?

Comment: If it's just a blob of text, no. There's nothing in there for Nearby Share to recognize as belonging to your app; you'd need to put that text into a file. Alternatively, you could format your text as a url and use Android App Links (https://developer.android.com/training/app-links) to prioritize your app on the receiving side.