# How to share via Nearby Share directly?

Tags: android, google-nearby, google-nearby-connections

related [Is there a way to share a link via Nearby Share & receive the link via a custom app on the second device using Nearby Connections API?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69993621/18469603)

as @Xlythe's answer, using *com.google.android.gms.nearby.sharing.EXTRA_REQUIRED_PACKAGE* can launch a package from receiver by Nearby

Question is how can i send a file with intent extra to Nearby directly.
guess i can use ACTION_SEND intent with Chooser dialog and make user select the Nearby button.
But is there a way to send to Nearby bypassing the chooser dialog?

And one more, suppose that a file sent to a receiver device with EXTRA_REQUIRED_PACKAGE value. receiver would get notification from Nearby to accept it and system would launch the package from extra value? and is the package able to handle a file that was sent from Nearby?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Intent action "com.google.android.gms.SHARE_NEARBY" and the package "com.google.android.gms" to directly launch Nearby Share.

Yes, the system launches the package with the action "android.intent.action.VIEW" and the intent extras from the received data.

Comment: thanks a lot! and can you check my next question? :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71890294/android-nearby-connection-send-payload-partially-wifi-aware-and-bluetooth

Comment: Hi, Am trying to use `Intent nearbyShareIntent = new Intent("com.google.android.gms.SHARE_NEARBY");
                nearbyShareIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.gms");
                startActivity(nearbyShareIntent);` but it gives me error while launching NearBy share.

Comment: Did you add data to the intent?